# PhoneGap set rounded corner to buttons or other elemets

Tags: css, cordova

I'm new in phone gap and I want to create simple rounded corner button like with web css buttons. but my simple code doesnet set the border radius correctly for elements

[image]

html code:

```
<a href="#" class="button big green rounded" data-corners="true" >Rounded</a>
```

css:

```
.button:active{
    /* Moving the button 1px to the bottom when clicked */
    bottom:-1px;
}

/* The three buttons sizes */

.button.big     { font-size:30px;}
.button.medium  { font-size:18px;}
.button.small   { font-size:13px;}

/* A more rounded button */

.button.rounded{
    -moz-border-radius:14em;
    border-radius:14em;
    -webkit-border-radius:14em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 14em;
```

Comment: As you see in your screenshot, the correct borders are rendered. However, there seems to be something 'behind' the button. Is there another element?